# Google Chrome malware warning

Tags: support

Whenever I open [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/80148), Google Chrome gives me a huge warning:

[image: Malware warning]

I was wondering if it could be because one of the images in the question came from a now-hijacked site or something. The Google diagnostic page is [here](http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jupiterinc.net%2Fstore%2Fimages%2FJACK25-35-unit.jpg&client=googlechrome&hl=en-US). If it is just one of the images, somebody with more rep than I do should remove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OP used an image that is hosted on a malicious reported URL. I removed the image and asked the OP to replace it with another. You should be fine now.

Comment: The OP's account has been 'deleted' so Molly won't do it, but it opens fine for me!

Comment: Thanks BloodPhilia! `:)`

Comment: @thepurplepixel You're welcome!

Comment: @ivoflipse It did open fine for me, it just didn't display the picture. I deleted reference to it. And I only just noticed you're from the Netherlands! lol!

Comment: The new image is most likely hot-linked, so it isn't really better...