# Why did Zonealarm warn me Stackoverflow could be phishing site?

Tags: support

I clicked on a *migrated question* from Stack Overflow and received this warning from ZoneAlarm:
[image: Stack1]
[image: Stack2]

Anything to be worried about?

Comment: Perhaps a problem with images on that page (similar to [this](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1823/google-chrome-malware-warning)), or maybe ZoneAlarm was dumb enough to think the code on the page was malicious.

Comment: [Link to question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490993/what-is-the-difference-between-mixin-module-and-mixinwith-module-in-perl)

Comment: @Manishearth - yes. I posted this on Stack Meta as well. you never know.

Comment: @Yannis thanks for the education. I did not know that they are all connected. I was simply trying to make the appropriate site aware of potential issue. I had best intentions at heart.

Comment: For reference: [Why would ZoneAlarm warn me Stackoverflow could be phising site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172430/why-would-zonealarm-warn-me-stackoverflow-could-be-phising-site)